# Handling memory leaks due to dynamic allocation inside a method without impacting signal/slot mechanism

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

How do I handle memory leak when using dynamic allocation inside a local function without compromising on signal/slot mechanism. I am using the client application which sends requests to server

Here's is my scenario:

```
MyClientApplication::sendRequestToServer()
{
    QString url_string = http://.....  // a url request
    QUrl url = url_string;

    QNetworkAccessManager *qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    connect(qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(handleResponseFromServer(QNetworkReply *)));
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = qnam->post(request);
}
```

I create many such requests in a member function of client application, each time using `QNetworkAccessManager` object which is dynamically created to send requests to server.

How do I handle the memory leak because of dynamic allocation of `qnam`? If I create the `qnam` object only on stack then how will the signal/slot mechanism work when the `sendRequestToServer()` returns from the call?

I want to solve the memory leak issue without compromising on the signal/slot mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how you could solve this issue, and it is difficult to say which one exactly would be the best in your particular scenario without understanding your use case more thoroughly.

However, your confusion is probably the fact that it matters for the `connect` mechanism if you use a pointer or stack object. The only thing that you need to make sure is that you have the object life cycle good enough.

This means, the object must be available when needed, so for instance after leaving the scope of the desidered, the object still must exist. It can be achieved with heap as well a stack objects.

#### Qt parent-child hierarchy

You could simple use make your `MyClientApplication` QObject subclass (directly or indirectly) the parent of the network access manager. This way, it is guaranteed that the child is only destructed when the parent is, i.e. when your MyClientApplication object stops to exist. Note that in this case, the object is not destructed when leaving the scope of the corresponding method, and that is why it can work. It will be deleted later based on the aforementioned rule.

Here is the necessary code change for that:

```
MyClientApplication::sendRequestToServer()
{

    QString url_string = http://.....  // a url request
    QUrl url = url_string;

    QNetworkAccessManager *qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); // This is how you set up the parent on the child    

    connect(qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(handleResponseFromServer(QNetworkReply *)));

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = qnam->post(request); // Naturally, you will need the stack object syntax here, respectively
}

This will probably be the easiest option for you to use based on the knowledge of your current code, so stick to this.
```

#### Member variable on the stack

You could simple use a stack object, initialized during the construction. This will have the necessary life-cycle aforementioned since it is only destructed during the destruction of your `MyClientApplication` class.

Here is the necessary code change for that:

```
class MyClientApplication...
{
    ...
    QNetworkAccessManager qnam; // This is the new member variable
    ...
};

MyClientApplication::sendRequestToServer()
{

    QString url_string = http://.....  // a url request
    QUrl url = url_string;

    // Here you need to get the address of the object since the connect function expects a pointer
    connect(&qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(handleResponseFromServer(QNetworkReply *)));

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = qnam.post(request); // Naturally, you will need the stack object syntax here, respectively
}

This would probably be the easiest option when you cannot use the Qt parent-child hierarchy.
```

#### Member variable on the heap

You could simple use a heap object, created during the construction and destroyed during the construction. This will have the necessary life-cycle aforementioned since it is only destructed during the destruction of your `MyClientApplication` class.

Here is the necessary code change for that:

```
class MyClientApplication...
{
    ...
    QNetworkAccessManager *qnam; // This is the new member variable
    ...
};

MyClientApplication::MyClientApplication(...)
: qnam(new QNetworkAccessManager())
...
{
    ...
}

MyClientApplication::~MyClientApplication()
{
    delete qnam;
    qnam = 0;
    ...
}

MyClientApplication::sendRequestToServer()
{

    QString url_string = http://.....  // a url request
    QUrl url = url_string;

    // Construction removed here since that is done in the constructor

    connect(qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(handleResponseFromServer(QNetworkReply *)));

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = qnam->post(request);
}

This is a bad practice in C++ in general to deal with the raw pointer explicitly. In certain cases, it makes sense, but if you do not have extra memory and performance concerns, this is not the way to go for. It is also error-prone if you forget to delete the raw pointer yourself.
```

#### Member variable on the heap with smart pointers

You could simple use a heap object, created during the construction and destroyed during the construction. This will have the necessary life-cycle aforementioned since it is only destructed during the destruction of your `MyClientApplication` class. You would use a smart pointer to deal with the automated destruction for you.

Here is the necessary code change for that:

```
class MyClientApplication...
{
    ...
    QPointer<QNetworkAccessManager> qnam; // This is the new member variable
    ...
};

MyClientApplication::MyClientApplication(...)
: qnam(new QNetworkAccessManager())
...
{
    ...
}

MyClientApplication::sendRequestToServer()
{

    QString url_string = http://.....  // a url request
    QUrl url = url_string;

    // Construction removed here since that is done in the constructor

    connect(qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(handleResponseFromServer(QNetworkReply *)));

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = qnam->post(request);
}

This is a good practice in C++ in general to deal with pointers due to the simplified maintenance. However, if you have a simple code as you pasted, this is probably an overengineered solution.
```

Hope this long explanation helps with avoiding the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the QNetworkAccessManager pointer ( `QNetworkAccessManager *qnam;` ) as a member variable in your class and only allocate once in the class constructor (call `qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);` it can take a parent, so you can pass `this` as parent when you construct the [QNetworkAccessManager](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details) and that way you don't need the delete call in destructor).

LE: also see the note in the documentation (it's not related to *QNetworkAccessManager*, but the reply will leak if you don't call `deleteLater()`):

> Note: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the user to delete the QNetworkReply object at an appropriate time. Do not directly delete it inside the slot connected to finished(). You can use the deleteLater() function.